# GNURadio 2D FFT

Tags: fft, gnuradio

I will preface this with saying I am a novice at this but I am trying to use GNURadio for RF object detection and would like to create a 3D "map" of objects in front of my antenna array. I intended to use a 2D Fast Fourier Transform for this but noted GNU Radio only offers a 1-D option through the "QT GUI Frequency Sink" block. Can I stack these to get the desired dimensions? Any tips and/or advice welcome on how to best approach this.

Currently using a simple QT GUI Sink to see the frequency response but would like an actual "image" for more precise and cleaner visualization. Haven't had an opportunity to try other blocks as of yet.